# CentOS 6.5 livecd ISO fails to boot in IBM x240 server

Tags: centos, livecd, ibm-unix-system-services

CentOS 6.5 live CD ISO downloaded from http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/6.5/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-LiveCD.iso fails to boot in my IBM x240 server.

`Boot Failed. IMM1:CD/DVD`

I tried Optimized boot options enable/disable but it did not work. Do i need to configure anything in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem is to change two things on the BIOS configuration

```
Boot Mode to "Legacy Mode"
Optimized Boot set to Enabled
```